# Terraform apply failed to save state: HTTP error: 308 on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, terraform, nodes

I've got an error when tried `terraform apply` to spin up a few nodes on Google, just preparing infra for the GitLab Ci/CD pipelines on Kubernetes.

```
terraform apply -auto-approve -lock=false       
google_container_cluster.default: Creating...
google_container_cluster.default: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
Failed to save state: HTTP error: 308


Error: Failed to persist state to backend.

The error shown above has prevented Terraform from writing the updated state
to the configured backend. To allow for recovery, the state has been written
to the file "errored.tfstate" in the current working directory.

Running "terraform apply" again at this point will create a forked state,
making it harder to recover.

To retry writing this state, use the following command:
    terraform state push errored.tfstate
```

Comment: It seems that terraform can't write the state file.  
Did you try to copy terraform state file to local environment and re-run `terraform apply` command?

Comment: where is your .tfstate being persisted ? The 308 error code = "Permanent Redirect", which means there might be a DNS/Server error on whatever you are using to persist the .tfstate.

Comment: It's in my local environment. I haven't moved it to GitLab yet, just gave it the first run. Also turning on Kubernetes services on Google cloud, but it asked me to add a new non-virtual card and increase a quota for the new project. Already done it and waiting to be approved :)

Comment: UPD: Got a suggestion to comment the line `backend "http" {}`.

Comment: Had an issue with my previous GC account, gave up and registered a new one. Couldn't figure out how to add the role in error: `Error 403: Required "container.clusters.create"`. Tried this script: `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding  gitops-project-290611 --role=roles/container.clusters.admin --member=serviceAccount:gitops-webinar@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com`, got the error: `ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Role roles/container.clusters.create is not supported for this resource`.


Terraform logs [link](https://pastebin.com/05btUi9f).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion from `Michael Crilly`, `@ninja` and `@ashishonnet` on `The DevOps Lounge` Discord community to comment the line `backend "http" {}` and try out a few other things. Actually commenting worked fine with `HTTP error: 308 on Google Cloud Platform`.

Thanks to `@guillaume blaquiere` he was right on [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64107669/error-403-required-container-clusters-create-after-terraform-apply-with-owner/64115693#64115693) when found out that I use project name instead of the project ID.

```
provider "google" {
 credentials = file("~/gitops-project-290611-01b6aabd6093.json")
 project     = "gitops-project-290611"
 region      = "us-central1-a"
}
```