# Error 403: Required "container.clusters.create" after Terraform apply with owner role of JSON key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, nodes, cluster-computing

I've already created a `service account` and added a `JSON` key with the owner role then downloaded from Chrome. Trying to create a Google cluster with `Terraform apply`, but getting this error: `2020/09/26 01:46:14 [ERROR] eval: *terraform.EvalApplyPost, err: googleapi: Error 403: Required "container.clusters.create" permission(s) for "projects/gitops-webinar"., forbidden`

Extended logs: https://pastebin.com/05btUi9f

Terraform `main.tf` file

```
provider "google" {
 credentials = file("~/gitops-project-290611-01b6aabd6093.json")
 project     = "gitops-webinar"
 region      = "us-central1-a"
}
```

$ ls -la gitops-project-290611-01b6aabd6093.json

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 organic  staff  2346 Sep 25 14:56 gitops-project-290611-01b6aabd6093.json
```

$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy  gitops-project-290611 | pbcopy

```
bindings:
- members:
  - deleted:serviceAccount:gitops-webinar-2@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com?uid=112358266788784007511
  - deleted:serviceAccount:gitops-webinar1@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com?uid=113184308230946951276
  role: roles/compute.admin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:gitops-webinar@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/compute.instanceAdmin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-782490657309@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/compute.serviceAgent
- members:
  - deleted:serviceAccount:gitops-webinar-2@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com?uid=112358266788784007511
  - deleted:serviceAccount:gitops-webinar1@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com?uid=113184308230946951276
  - serviceAccount:gitops-webinar@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/container.admin
- members:
  - deleted:serviceAccount:gitops-webinar1@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com?uid=113184308230946951276
  role: roles/container.clusterAdmin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-782490657309@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/container.serviceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:gitops-webinar@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/containeranalysis.ServiceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:gitops-webinar@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/containeranalysis.admin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-782490657309@containerregistry.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/containerregistry.ServiceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:782490657309@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:gitops-webinar@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/editor
- members:
  - deleted:serviceAccount:gitops-webinar-2@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com?uid=112358266788784007511
  - serviceAccount:gitops-webinar@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
- members:
  - deleted:serviceAccount:gitops-webinar-2@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com?uid=112358266788784007511
  - serviceAccount:gitops-webinar@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  - deleted:serviceAccount:terraform@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com?uid=115339463706838203610
  - user:shuraisaeva2@gmail.com
  role: roles/owner
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-782490657309@cloud-redis.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/redis.serviceAgent
- members:
  - deleted:serviceAccount:gitops-webinar1@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com?uid=113184308230946951276
  role: roles/resourcemanager.organizationAdmin
- members:
  - deleted:serviceAccount:gitops-webinar-2@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com?uid=112358266788784007511
  role: roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:gitops-webinar@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/secretmanager.admin
- members:
  - deleted:serviceAccount:gitops-webinar1@gitops-project-290611.iam.gserviceaccount.com?uid=113184308230946951276
  role: roles/storage.admin
etag: BwWwOdndDu0=
version: 1
```

Comment: What is the content of your JSON file (without the private key)?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere right here: https://pastebin.com/uNf487S3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the issue. You use the project name and not the project ID. Try this

```
provider "google" {
 credentials = file("~/gitops-project-290611-01b6aabd6093.json")
 project     = "gitops-project-290611"
 region      = "us-central1-a"
}
```

You haven't access on the `gitops-webinar` project_id